# Is It possible to install 240V dryer outlet In my condo with 100 Amp panel

Tags: electrical

In my my 1 bedroom condo I have an electrical panel 100 AMP photo below,
I'm looking to install a 240V dryer plug. I currently have a washer dryer in one combo that runs on a 120V outlet with water hook up already installed. I just wanted to know if this is possible as I would like to eventually switch to a separate washer, and ventless dryer which runs on a 240V outlet.

[image: Electrical panel]

Comment: Can you get us the physical dimensions of this panel? (height by width)

Answer (score 3):

The good news: you could move breaker 11 to 1 or 9 and then put a double breaker in 10/11.

The bad news: these panels have a very bad reputation. See https://inspectapedia.com/fpe/Federal_Pioneer_Panel_Safety.php and [Federal Pioneer panel safety](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103851/federal-pioneer-panel-safety)  for some details. It is a good idea to get a reputable electrician to check the panel and possibly replace it.

Comment: The  French on the label suggests this unit is a Canadian model, which have far fewer problems than the US models.

Comment: @nobody -- the OG stabloks are bad news even in Canada -- the Schneider-built ones *may* be better, but it's hard to tell

Answer (score 1):

FYI, here is how your panel [is phased](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/110152/47125) (behind the curtain).  Notice how 240V breakers are positioned so half is on each phase.  Your 30A/240V dryer breaker will need the same.

[image]

Remember you must use /3+ground cable to a dryer.  Using /2+ground is not allowed, because dryers need neutral, and the exemption that once allowed bootlegging ground off neutral has been gone for decades.

Comment: Amazing how they can get all the subatomic particles to organize by [color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge).